# Do asserts get stripped out in GAE Python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, assert

My understanding of Python asserts is that are meant for debugging and that they don't get executed for "optimized" Python code (`python -O`).

For production app engine code, is `-O` used and thus stripping asserts or will asserts get executed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran a test on the platforms I use to know for sure.  Asserts do get executed for:

- GAE standard first generation
- GAE flexible

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand from Python asserts, once you set the global assertions to -0 they all become "null-operations" as in, they will get compiled but won't be evaluated or have they're conditional expressions executed.

They get set like that at the Python interpreter level so i don't think that GAE actually affects that.